# Breaking of wadu during prayer

Tags: salat, fiqh, wudu, reference-request, taharah

If we recite prayer and sudden blow off and wadu breakdown then what order for us to to complete prayer.
Explain me based on hadith and fiqh references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given below is the view of Maalikis,Shaafa‘is and Hanbalis, except the Hanafis 
The one who loses his wudoo during the prayer, by passing wind or otherwise, should go and do wudoo again, then come back and start the prayer from the beginning all over again.
 According to above as for the one who breaks his wudoo’ deliberately, his prayer becomes invalid. 
Ash-Shaafa‘i (may Allah have mercy on him) interpreted the reports about some of the Sahaabah exiting the prayer because of nosebleed, then going to do wudoo again and then resuming the prayer from where they left off as referring to washing away the blood, not wudoo’ in the sense of ablution for prayer. 
And Allah knows best.